# Using @media to change positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem that's driving me crazy because I know the solution is likely right in front of my eyes. I have a dropdown menu that I want to change on the screen reaching a size. Here is the snippet of what it it is like when it's unedited.

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  max-height: 45px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
.box button {
  float: left;
  background-color: #34495e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      $("#Dropdown").click(function() {
        $("#Home").toggle();
        $("#Profile").toggle();
        $("#Group").toggle();
        $("#Projects").toggle();
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="Dropdown">
        <img src="menu.png">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Home">Home</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Profile">Profile</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Group">Group</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Projects">Projects</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This works fine and how I want it. But my trouble comes when I try to change the float value when the screen reaches a certain size by doing the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

#Dropdown {display: block;}

.box button {
    float: top;
    display:  inline-block;
}

.box {

float: top; 
position: static; 
top: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
max-height: 45px;
max-width: 150px;

}

}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work right. It should appear like the following page:

```css
.box {
  float: top;
  margin-top: 0px;
  max-height: 45px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
.box button {
  float: top;
  background-color: #34495e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      $("#Dropdown").click(function() {
        $("#Home").toggle();
        $("#Profile").toggle();
        $("#Group").toggle();
        $("#Projects").toggle();
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="Dropdown">
        <img src="menu.png">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Home">Home</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Profile">Profile</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Group">Group</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button id="Projects">Projects</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is a pretty long winded question so any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there is no css command `float:top;`. `float` can take the parameters: `left`, `right`, `none`, `inline-start`, `inline-end`.

Comment: Maybe not right now, but it does appear that `float: top` is something that has been considered for inclusion: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-floats-3/#float-property

Comment: Yes there is a float:top css command on the page, but that page is a working draft. it's a kind of recommendation or future plan.

Comment: I was just pointing it out. Maybe you should provide an alternative solution as the answer provided seems more along the lines of a comment.

Comment: Of course I would like to help, but I am struggling to understand what you want when the page reaches 768px. Would you like horizontal menu as it is showed in 1st snipper after 768px ? Furthermore, if you describe what you want I can provide alternative responsive CSS solution like flex-box or there are a lot of jquery plug in about dropdown menu. Also editable snippet would be better :)

Comment: @u238 Thank you this actually solved my problem! I was setting the float to top in the first example but it defaulted to none because top doesn't exist, so when I wanted to change it back to float: top using the media query it didn't change because it doesn't exist, but I should have been changing it back to float: none. Thanks!